# Webpack dev server with web and webworker entries ignores html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I have two entry points for my Webpack dev server. The first is my `web` app, and the second is a bundle used for a web worker. I would like to use `webpack-dev-server` to continously build and serve *both* the web app and the web worker.

I have written my `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env['NODE_ENV'] === 'production';

const mode = isProduction ? 'production' : 'development';

module.exports = [
  {
    mode,
    devtool: isProduction ? null : 'source-map',
    target: 'webworker',
    entry: './worker/worker.fsproj',
    output: {
      filename: 'worker.js',
      path: __dirname,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.fs(x|proj)?$/,
          use: 'fable-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    mode,
    target: 'web',
    entry: './app.fsproj',
    output: {
      filename: '[hash].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? null : 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'App',
        template: 'index.ejs',
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.fs(x|proj)?$/,
          use: 'fable-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      stats: 'minimal',
      proxy: {
        '/graphql': 'http://localhost:4000',
      },
    },
  },
];
```

This builds the worker bundle correctly and serves it at `/worker.js`. However, it does not serve the web app and instead gives a directory listing.

How can I get Webpack to build and serve both entries?

---

**Update**

If I do not use `html-webpack-plugin` and instead write my own `index.html` then Webpack works correctly.

So the question is: why does `HtmlWebpackPlugin` get ignored when doing a multi-config Webpack build?

Comment: I think you need to add more info in your devServer node like `publicPath`, `contentBase` in order to start webpack server in the same folder as your index.html.

If you don't have an index.html to serves, it will indeed show a listing of the directory content.

Comment: My `index.html` should be generated by `HtmlWebpackPlugin` but perhaps I have misconfigured this.

Comment: Yes, `HtmlWebpackPlugin` should generate it indeed but I don't remember where it puts it by default. I remember having the same problem as you in the past and it was not putting where I was expecting it.

To check, you can build your application in non watch mode in order to see where it's being printed and try to look if that the same place where other files are etc.